# Does it have to make a heap copy of a block if the block is used in a dispatch_after function in a method

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I am trying to make a cancellble block and this is my code:

```
typedef void(^dispatch_cancelable_block_t)(BOOL canceled);

dispatch_cancelable_block_t dispatch_after_with_cancel(NSTimeInterval delay, dispatch_block_t block) {
    if (block == nil) {
        return nil;
    }

    __block dispatch_block_t originalBlock = [block copy];
    __block dispatch_cancelable_block_t cancelableBlock = [^(BOOL canceled){
        if (!canceled && originalBlock) {
            originalBlock();
        }
        originalBlock = nil;
    } copy];

    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delay * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if (cancelableBlock) {
            cancelableBlock(NO);
            cancelableBlock = nil;
        }
    });

    return cancelableBlock;
}
```

and the block can be cancelled using this function:

```
void cancel_block(dispatch_cancelable_block_t block) {
    if (block == nil) {
        return;
    }
    block(YES);
    block = nil;
}
```

I have searched for a while but everything I got was written 3 or 4 years ago which might not have included the recent change of Apple.

My question would be is the [block copy] and the copy of cancelableBlock still needed under ARC? Do we still need to make a copy of block or with __block specifier the block is retained already? What are the other potential differences between blocks and other objective c objects in terms of memory management?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to the [Clang documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#blocks) you don't have to worry:
__ *block variables of retainable object owner type are moved off the stack by initializing the heap copy with the result of moving from the stack copy.*
So ARC will do everything for you.

I think all this `[copy]` stuff originated by some bug in LLVM that has been fixed long ago.